# Can an Android app have more than one Services?

Tags: android

Service is one of the components of Android.

Can an Android app have more than one Services? Can I let a Service start on startup without an Activity? How to do that?

Is one of the 4 components(Activities,Services,Content providers,Broadcast receivers) the smallest unit I can control(I mean I can let it start on startup) in Android?

Can I registe a method of a class and let it run on startup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes you can have more than one service in an application.
2. you you can start a service on boot.

   In your manifest element:

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

   In your application element

   `<receiver android:name="com.example.BroadcastReceiver">

   <intent-filter>

       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

   </intent-filter>

   </receiver>`

In BroadcastReceiver.java:

```
public class Broadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, Service.class);
    context.startService(startServiceIntent);
}
}
```

I hope that answers your problems.